# DataTable expressions referencing to two different tables

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, expression

I have two hidden Datatables, one of which gets its data from a database, and the other from a static .csv file. I want to create a DataGridView with columns that has custom datatable expressions (just like a spreadsheet).

My question is: how do I formulate expressions in the datagridview to search for data in the other two tables?

Example: Table B has references for each product, a static unique id. Table A also have a reference to each product but also includes status for that product. 
In the DataGridView I have three columns (ID, PRODUCT, STATUS). How can I write the expressions to fetch data from the other tables?

This is just how I think this can be solved, if you have another idea please let me know.

Thank you!

[image: process flow]

Comment: So is the issue that you need to join two DataTables together so it can be displayed in the DataGridView. Did I sum that up correctly, or is that not the goal?

Comment: Use linq to join the fields and 'create' a view by using the `select new { ....}` of linq.

Comment: both tables have same Products  ? same products id's ?

Comment: The objective is **not** to join the two tables together. The datagridview can be seen as a third table where I have to use `DataColumn.Expression` in order to find and extrapolate data from the other tables. Think of it like excel sheets where you need to reference other sheet in the formula.

Comment: use linq2dataset. this url may help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c941bb0a-31a6-4edd-a2ac-a1a4d48cc4ce/create-dataview-from-two-tables?forum=adodotnetdataset

Answer (score 0):

**using Merge two tables**

```
 1- convert table1 to dataTable dtOne.
 2- convert csv data to dataTable  dtTwo.
 3-  dtAll = new Datatable();



 dtAll = dtOne.Copy();
 dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);
 dataGridView.DataSource=dtAll;
```

Comment: I don't want to merge the tables. Rather extrapolate the data. Just like in excel when you, in a formula, want to reference other sheets.

Comment: Add the columns to the grid, the columns you want to show only
Then I work the LOP on one of the tables and draw from each row the values that correspond to the columns
In each row of table A corresponds to a row in table B, you can get the corresponding row by query.
grid.rows.add (new gridrow (new object [] {value1, value2, valu3, ...., valuen})